# SQL Server stored procedure without parameter flagged as high risk in Veracode source code review

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, sqlclient, veracode

I have scanned my ASP.NET MVC Project in Veracode, one of the results is High, and that is a possible risk of SQL injection, it points out on my code where t calls a stored procedure that has no parameter. I don't know how to deal with this or should I tag it as a false positive?

Well my colleagues is advising me to modified my stored procedure by putting a parameter even without using it on the script. But I would have to edit every stored procedure that has no parameter.

Here is my code that calls the stored procedure without parameter:

```
Public Function queryDS(sqlString As String, isStoredProcedure As Boolean, srcTable As String) As DataSet

    Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(connectionName).ToString

    Using sqlConn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)

        Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand(sqlString, sqlConn)
        If isStoredProcedure = True Then
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        Else
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        End If

        sqlConn.Open()
        Dim sqlDA As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        sqlDA.Fill(ds, srcTable)

        Return ds

    End Using
```

That is no error it's just it's a risk according to Veracode.

Comment: You're executing arbitrary SQL that is passed in via `sqlString`. It allows for potential SQL injection, as far as Veracode (or anyone else reading it) can tell. It's not a false positive. There is an apparent risk here.

Comment: I think the issue is your `sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text`. Why do you allow `isStoredProcedure = false`?

Comment: Hi everyone I create a reusable method for calling stored procedures or sql strings.

Comment: That "reusable method" is a really bad idea - based on the **Single Responsibility Principle**, every piece of code should do only one thing - so I'd strongly recommend to have **one** method for executing stored procedures, and another method to execute "ad-hoc" SQL queries